# Python Parallel processing to get google results

Tags: python, multiprocessing

**New to programming user**

I am trying to run three URLs (google search) in Python and can do so individually by using the following lines of repetitive code :

```
import requests
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 #Get Google number of results for option 1
url1 = 'https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=test'
r1 = requests.get(url1)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.text, "lxml")
res1 = soup1.find("div", {"id": "resultStats"})
print(res1.text)

#Get Google number of results for option 2
url2 = 'https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=test2'
r2 = requests.get(url2)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, "lxml")
res2 = soup2.find("div", {"id": "resultStats"})
print(res2.text)

#Get Google number of results for option 3
url3 = 'https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=test3'
r3 = requests.get(url3)
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(r3.text, "lxml")
res3 = soup3.find("div", {"id": "resultStats"})
print(res3.text)
```

I needed  help to run them using parallel processing so all three can be run simultaneously instead of one after other (to save some time). I tried looking into some of the multiprocessing approach but could not get it to work properly because of my limited understanding. Can someone please help me re-write this if it's something easy (or any pseudocode logic that will help me get started) from a multi processing approach?

Comment: You can try grequests package.

Comment: What have tried or researched so far?